# When do you use what word to express that something consists of something else?

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, word-usage

There are various ways of saying that something consists of something else:

- composed of
- comprised of
- <strike>contained in</strike>
- consist of

Maybe there are more. Are there hard and fast rules when to use which or are they synonyms?

Comment: Ummm. In my neck of the woods we usually just say **is**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't understand. _A book is pages?_

Comment: I was joking a bit, but yes - it *is*. More naturally, perhaps, an entry in a dictionary **is** one or more definitions, examples, and etymology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some thoughts:

- "composed of" refers to the parts of a thing from the point of view of the subject
- "comprising" or "comprises" (not "comprised of" though ardent descriptivists will gnash their teeth at me) can refer to either.
- "contained in" refers to the container from the point of view of its constituent parts
- "consist of" or "consists of" refers to the elements of a thing, with the added implication that these elements are *sine qua non* — without them, the thing would not be what it is.

Comment: In retrospect I think it was an error on my part to include _contained in_ which has clearly nothing to do with the rest. Thank you for your answer. I hope others will provide feedback too. Otherwise it'll be a bit hard for me to say if it's correct or not.

Comment: Even I won't gnash my teeth at you.  "Comprised of" is arising from an error (like *irregardless*), and even if it could one day become an accepted standard (which it certainly could), at the moment you risk appearing as though you have a poor command of the finer points of English if you use this construction.

Comment: Unfortunately this question didn't get as much attention as I hoped. Or maybe this answer sums it up best? Anyway, I'll accept it because it's certainly useful.

Answer (score 4):

There are some works relating the relatively mature field of [mereology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mereology) to natural languages; Wikipedia barely mentions them. I am not an expert on this particular crossroads, but I'm afraid that the ambiguity of natural language won't let you find hard and fast rules as you request. "Parts: A Study in Ontology" by Simons 1987 is the work that I know best about this, and you may find it useful if you are interested in a detailed study of the matter.

Comment: +1 Just hang on. We need many more such answers around here.